# VisualSVN messed up my localhost in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, port, visualsvn-server

**EDIT:**
The localhost seem to be working fine in my firefox, IE and even Chrome's incognito mode. These is a problem specific to chrome. Any ideas?

**PREVIOUS:**
I just uninstalled VisualSVN Server from my Windows 7. But now when I try to hit localhost, I get redirected to `localhost/svn`. I am using WAMP and developing something that requires the root access. I can not put the project in a sub directory. I have also tried `netstat -ao` but no process is using ports 80 or 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have solved the problem....but for future, those who came here like me looking for a solution to this, this seems to be a prob for browser cache....clearing browser cache history solves the problem.....did for me...

Comment: That's exactly what it took me to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you *uninstalled* VisualSVN Server, then it's some other application which runs on 80 / 443 port that redirects you to `/svn`. Some steps that may help you to determine the root cause:

1. Verify that VisualSVN Server has been successfully uninstalled.

   - Start `appwiz.cpl` and see whether VisualSVN Server is listed as the installed application,
   - Start `services.msc` and see whether "VisualSVN Server" service is listed.
2. Run `netstat -anbv` and see which app runs on HTTP(S) port.